# Unable to compile C++ code: invalid conversion from 'Node*' to 'int'

Tags: c++, arrays, object

I have this C++ class with an array of Node objects called `adj` (I guess you don't need to see the implementation of my Node class)

```
class Graph {
public:
    Node *adj;
    bool *marked;
    int nVertex, p;
    int *distance;

    void graph(int quantity);
    bool is_marked();

    void cleaner();
    void newVertex(int value);
};
```

And I have this method which creates a node `nod` and tries to store it in the p-th position in `adj`:

```
void Graph::newVertex(int value)
{
    Node *nod = new Node(value);
    adj[p++] = nod;
}
```

When I try to compile this code I get the following error message:

`invalid conversion from 'Node*' to 'int'`

I can't see what I have done wrong in my code. The array initialization looks right to me and the object assignment too. Please help me answer this question.

UPDATE: the code for the `Node` class:

```
class Node {
public:
    int value, cost;
    Node *next;

    Node() {}

    Node(int val) {
        value = val;
        next = NULL;
        cost = 0;
    }
};
```

UPDATE: I can't use C++ vector here. I'd love to but it's for a homework thing. Before anyone thinks I am cheating or something, please note that I'm not asking for a solution to my specific assigned problem, but instead to a problem that I am having for compiling the code.

Comment: Hint: you rather want `std::vector<Node>`...

Comment: `adj` is a pointer to `Node`. You can probably make it point to an element of an array of `Nodes`. But you can't make it point to an element of an array of `Node*`.

Comment: show the constructor of Node

Comment: "...the p-th position in `adj`...".  ?!?  `adj` is declared as `Node *`, not as an array or something similar. Did you mean to declare `adj` as `Node **adj` or `Node *adj[10]` or something else array-like?

Comment: Ohh, I see. Looks like I don't know C/C++ arrays yet. Just updated it to `Node **adj;` and to `*adj = new Node[quantity + 1];` in my `Graph` constructor and things are working!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The type of `adj[p++]` is clearly `Node&` and you try to assign a `Node*` to it. I guess, your `Node` type has a constructor taking an `int` and the compiler tries but fails to convert the `Node*` to an `int`.

You probably meant to declare `adj` as

```
std::vector<Node*> adj;
```

... and then add new nodes using, e.g.:

```
adj.push_back(nod);
```

(note, that you still need to make sure the allocated objects get released at the appropriate point in time).

Answer (score 2):

`adj` is of type `Node*`. `adj[someIndex]` is then of type `Node`. You are trying to assign `Node*` to `Node`. My educated guess is, you have `Node::operator=(int)`, so the compiler tries to interpret your code that way - but that doesn't work out either, producing the error message you observe.

Comment: @Cole Johnson: in C++, there ain't no such thing as an expression of a reference type. [ 5p5: If an expression initially has the type “reference to T” (8.3.2, 8.5.3), the type is adjusted to T prior to any further analysis. The expression designates the object or function denoted by the reference, and the expression is an lvalue or an xvalue, depending on the expression.] `adj[someIndex]` is not of reference type even initially.

Comment: whoops. My mistake. I was thinking about if you call a function that takes a `Node&`.

Answer (score 1):

OK, with the definition of the `Node` class in hand I think I can see what you're trying to do.  If I'm correct, you want to have `Graph::adj` point to a linked list of `Node` elements, with each `Node` then pointing to the next `Node` in the list. If that's correct the implementation of `new_vertex` needs to look something like:

```
void Graph::newVertex(int value)
  {
  Node *nod = new Node(value);
  nod->next = adj;
  adj = nod;
  }
```

No need to have an index (`p`) - you'd just walk the linked list of `Node` elements with code similar to

```
Node *n = adj;

while(n != NULL)
  {
  // do something useful with n

  n = n->next;
  }
```

If you really insist upon using array syntax to access elements of the linked list (bad idea in my mind, as it just adds to the potential confusion, but YMMV) you could add something like

```
Node *operator[](int n);  // 0-based index into Node list
```

to `Graph` with an implementation similar to

```
Node *operator[](int ndx)
  {
  Node *n = adj;

  for( ; n != NULL, ndx > 0 ; ndx--)
    n = n->next;

  return n;
  }
```

Share and enjoy,.

Answer (score 1):

After you have created your new `Node`:

```
Node *nod = new Node(value);
```

you need to hook it up to your linked list. A linked list looks like:

```
[HEAD] => [value|next] => [value|next] => NULL
```

where `HEAD` in your case would be `adj`.

Therefore, you need to update the next of your new node to point to the current head node, then update the head node to point to the new node.

That is, you should end up with something like:

```
adj => [value|next] => [value|next] => ... => NULL
       ^               ^
       nod             adj'
```

where `adj'` is the old value of `adj`.

It helps to create diagrams of what the data structure looks like and how the values are being updated.

You then need to work out how to traverse the nodes in the list.

Also, don't forget to clean up the nodes in the `Graph` destructor (and be careful how you do that).